# Illegal SELECT statement within scalar SQL function

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL script that checks a field in a table for invalid characters. When I execute the script, I get an error:

> Illegal SELECT statement within a scalar SQL function.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsValueValid (@Value NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Value = RTRIM(ltrim(@Value))

    IF (@Value IS NULL) OR (@Value = '')
        RETURN 1

    DECLARE @len INT
    DECLARE @index INT
    DECLARE @ascii INT

    SELECT @len =  LEN(@Value), @index = 1

    WHILE (@index <= @len)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ascii = ASCII(substring(@Value, @index, 1))

        IF ((@ascii BETWEEN 48 AND 57)
            OR (@ascii BETWEEN 65 AND 90)
            OR (@ascii BETWEEN 97 AND 122)
            OR (@ascii = 32)
            OR (@ascii = 45)
            OR (@ascii = 95)
           )
        BEGIN
            SELECT @index = @index + 1
            CONTINUE
        END
        ELSE
            RETURN 0
    END

    RETURN 1
END

--select invalid record
SELECT obj_usr_num
FROM dsk_obj
WHERE dbo.IsValueValid([obj_usr_num]) = 0
```

Comment: Change the `SELECT`s in the procedure to `SET`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I updated all the SELECT values to SET, but still received the same message.